# Is it possible to display windows which are bigger than monitor resolution?

Tags: resolution, window

I want test my game for retina displays, which has 2048×1536 resulution, but my monitor small and I don't see the whole window. Is it possible make this window smaller and save 2048x1536 resolution of game?

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that. If your monitor doesn't support a particular resolution, then you can't display an application at that resolution.